What is the propper way of adding test files into the existing project with CMake?
I have a git repository with my laboratory works. They are all interconnected and each one uses something from the other one (e.g. binary search tree laboratory work uses allocator and logger, which are separate works each).
Initially, repository had basically all the files needed, the making of laboratory work was so that you have to write your realization of a particular data structure into the .cpp file for each work. But then I found some files missing: we have tests for each work, tests consist of test.cpp file and CMakeLists file for the particular test scenario.
As I had done one of the tasks and wanted to test it, I created a new test.cpp file (since it was not provided there) and basically copied the contents of another CMakeLists file from other task into the empty CMakeLists, which was provided at the directory of the current task.
Now starts the main problem:
In my code I used including headers with <> (e.g. #include <binary_search_tree.h>). This was done with linking libraries in corresponing CMakeLists files. As I created and launched the new test file with "new" CMakeLists file, my IDE (CLion 2024.1) started to show me that including with <> is a compilation error :
g++.exe D:\stud\GITrepos\mp_os\arithmetic\fraction\tests\tests.cpp -o tests
In file included from 
[path here]\mp_os\arithmetic\fraction\tests\tests.cpp:6:
[path here]/mp_os/arithmetic/fraction/include/fraction.h:5:10: fatal error: big_integer.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <big_integer.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated. 

Immediately after that, other tasks, that worked correctly, had the same issue - including with <> (or even with "", if I used it with header name only? wthout its relative path) appeared as compilation error.
I rolled back the changes, and it turned out, that just the presence of test.cpp file provokes such errors - as soon as I deleted it, all the errors disappeared (again, all the other files remained the same as when they worked correctly).
Summary:
Wanted to test if my task was done correctly;
Creating of additional .cpp file provokes errors.
Questions: Why does another .cpp file provokes an error? What's the propper way of testing my task in this case?
Tried solutions:
Using CLion "Repair IDE" tool and invalidating cache;
Copying files from a correctly working similar project of my colleague;
Nothing had any effect.
On picture is a proejct directory hierarchy of my colleague's working project. File tests.cpp was absent originally. 
Contents of fraction/tests/CMakeLists.txt (Originally empty) below:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(arthmtc_fraction_tests)

# For Windows users: prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
# set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_executable(
        arthmtc_fraction_tests
        fraction_tests.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
        arthmtc_fraction_tests
        PUBLIC
        arthmtc_frctn)
set_target_properties(
        arthmtc_fraction_tests PROPERTIES
        LANGUAGES CXX
        LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
        CXX_STANDARD 14
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
        CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF
        VERSION 1.0
        DESCRIPTION "fraction implementation library fraction tests")



"In my code I used including headers with <>", "my IDE (CLion 2024.1) started to show me that including with <> is a compilation error" - Do not describe a code and error messages. Instead add them into the question post exactly as they are, in form of [mcve].

Does arthmtc_frctn provide PUBLIC/INTERFACE for include?

Is the error from IDE only, or compilation fail too?

@Tsyvarev edited, thank you.

@Jarod42

Not quite sure what you mean. I am pretty lame at CMake.
Here is a part of code of what I think we're talking about in CMakeLists for arthmtc_frctn:
target_include_directories(mp_os_arthmtc_frctn PUBLIC ./include)
This file is at arithmetic/fraction
Error is a compilation fail.


I indeed mean target_include_directories. Is it a bad copy/paste? you provide for target mp_os_arthmtc_frctn whereas you use arthmtc_frctn...

The command line in the error message g++.exe D:\stud\GITrepos\mp_os\arithmetic\fraction\tests\tests.cpp -o tests is definitely not generated from CMake project. Such line is generated by CLion when you ask it to compile a particular file. Obviously that compilation doesn't know about include directories specified in CMakeLists.txt.

@Jarod42 you're right, it was a bad copy/paste. In fact I have "mp_os" in all library names in the project, I omitted it in my question for the sake of simplification. In this particular case, please, consider arthmtc_frctn and mp_os_arthmtc_frctn the same thing.

@Tsyvarev You were absolutely right. I was trying to execute one separate file with tests. Thank you very much.

As @Tsyvarev noticed, I was running one separate .cpp file, which was the reason. When launching a configuration, there appeared to be no problem.
